# Are there debugging Symbols for Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, debugging

Is it possible to debug issues with stuff like wsstracing? Or is the disassembly the best I can get?

MOSS 2007 SP2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer myself: No, there aren't.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [Microsoft Public Symbol Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552208(v=vs.85).aspx). If the Sharepoint symbols are not there, your next best bet would be to install debug Windows Server from an MSDN subscription and get the symbols for it from there.

The actual symbol server is at [this URL](http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols). However, it is not browsable in a browser, it's useful only in WinDbg.

Comment: All three of your links are now down. Please update :)

Answer (score 1):

.NET Reflector now has a "Pro" version which will allow you to step through and debug just about any third party assembly including the SharePoint assemblies (with the exception of code that is obfuscated).

I actually just downloaded it today, and it looks really good! It integrates with Visual Studio, and is seamless when stepping from your own code into the SharePoint assembly's code.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm

Comment: That only works with .net code though. For debugging problems in native code, it won't do much good sadly :(